# How to play sound when a notification pops up?

Tags: java, android, audio, notifications

I'm working on an app where using two switch buttons the user can turn on/off notifications and notification sound. I created the notifications that pop up on the status bar and I want to play a default sound when they appear.I wrote the following code but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas about how can I make the notification sound play ?

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

import java.util.Set;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;
import static android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
import static com.example.myevents.R.drawable.notification;


public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
    Switch simpleswitch1;
    Switch simpleswitch2;
    private Notification notification;
    NotificationManager manager;
    Notification myNotication;
    boolean enableSound = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


        simpleswitch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleswitch1);
        simpleswitch2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleswitch2);
        simpleswitch1.setChecked(false);
        simpleswitch2.setChecked(false);
        simpleswitch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        int notifyID = 1;
                        String CHANNEL_SOUND_ID = "channel SOUND";// The id of the channel.
                        CharSequence NAME_SOUND = "channel 1";// The user-visible name of the channel.
                        String CHANNEL_SILENT_ID = "channel SILENT";// The id of the channel.
                        CharSequence NAME_SILENT = "channel 2";// The user-visible name of the channel.
                        int importance_sound = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                        int importance_silent = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
                        NotificationChannel mChannel_sound = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_SOUND_ID, NAME_SOUND, importance_sound);
                        NotificationChannel mChannel_silent = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_SILENT_ID, NAME_SILENT, importance_silent);

                        // Crete both notification channels
                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel_sound);
                        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel_silent);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this, Visitor.class);
                        intent.putExtra("yourpackage.notifyId", notifyID);
                        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Settings.this, 0, intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


                        // Select the correct notification channel
                        String selectedChannelId;
                        if (enableSound) {
                            selectedChannelId = CHANNEL_SOUND_ID;
                        } else {
                            selectedChannelId = CHANNEL_SILENT_ID;
                        }

                        // Create a notification and set the notification channel.
                        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Settings.this, selectedChannelId);
                        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cheers);
                        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
                        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Notification");
                        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
                        notificationBuilder.setChannelId(selectedChannelId);

                        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();


                        // Issue the notification.
                        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);

                    }}});
                simpleswitch2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        enableSound = isChecked;
                    }
                });






            }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a flag to toggle the sound on/off. This could be a boolean value controlled by the second switch. Then check the status of that flag when creating the notification and decide to set or not the sound.

And maybe split the `Notification` from the `NotificationBuilder` to control the sound.

1- Create the flag being a Class attribute

```java
Switch simpleswitch1;
Switch simpleswitch2;
private Notification notification;
NotificationManager manager;
Notification myNotication;

// Sound disabled by default
boolean enableSound = false;
```

2- Control the flag with the second switch

```java
simpleswitch2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        enableSound = isChecked;
    }
});
```

3- Use the `NotificationBuilder` to control the sound. Replace this piece of code from first switch

```java
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Settings.this, CHANNEL_ID);
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("NOTIFICATION TITLE");
notificationBuilder.setContentText("You have a new notification");
notificationBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);

if (enableSound){
    notificationBuilder.setSound(android.provider.Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000,100});
}

Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
```

I hope it helps!

## UPDATE

I think I know why it's not playing a sound. I've just created a new Android Studio Project and copy-paste your code and the notifications is fired, the sound plays and I can not turn the sound off (just the oppostite). And I'm guessing your problem is related to the **notification channel**. Then I modify my App and it worked!

First, let me correct myself. The `PRIORITY` has been deprecated since api level 26 (*which you are using according to `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)`*) and what you should use instead is the `IMPORTANCE` in the `NotificationChannel`. The problem with a notification channel is that you can not edit it once created (unless you uninstall your app). So if at first you where using a **low** importance channel and then change it to a **high** one it won't take any effect.

So what you really need is two notifications channel: one with sound and one silent, and then select the appropiate channel with the help of the previously created flag.

So now, the code for the first switch would be: *Notice I re-arrange it so I first create the NotificationChannel (for better readability)*

```java
if (isChecked){
    int notifyID = 1;
    String CHANNEL_SOUND_ID = "channel SOUND";// The id of the channel.
    CharSequence NAME_SOUND = "channel 1";// The user-visible name of the channel.
    String CHANNEL_SILENT_ID = "channel SILENT";// The id of the channel.
    CharSequence NAME_SILENT = "channel 2";// The user-visible name of the channel.
    int importance_sound = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    int importance_silent = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
    NotificationChannel mChannel_sound = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_SOUND_ID, NAME_SOUND, importance_sound);
    NotificationChannel mChannel_silent = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_SILENT_ID, NAME_SILENT, importance_silent);

    // Crete both notification channels
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel_sound);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel_silent);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this, Visitor.class);
    intent.putExtra("yourpackage.notifyId", notifyID);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Settings.this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    // Select the correct notification channel
    String selectedChannelId;
    if (enableSound){
        selectedChannelId = CHANNEL_SOUND_ID;
    }else{
        selectedChannelId = CHANNEL_SILENT_ID;
    }

    // Create a notification and set the notification channel.
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Settings.this, selectedChannelId);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Notification Text");
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    notificationBuilder.setChannelId(selectedChannelId);

    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();


        // Issue the notification.
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID , notification);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I updated the post to show you how I modified the code and maybe you can point out what I did wrong :)

Comment: And what error do you get? O it just does not play sound? Try setting the notification as HIGH_PRIORITY `notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);`

Comment: It just doesn't play a sound. I also tried setting it as HIGH PRIORITY but it didn't work again.

Comment: Please look at the update on the answer! I think that's what you need to do. Best regards!

Comment: Thanks so much again! I modified the code as you said(I updated the post) but still in my phone Android 9 the sound doesn't play. Maybe it's my phone, I don't know..

Comment: It's very odd... As said, I've created a new project and copy-paste that code and works! In Android 9. Can you test with an Emulator? Notice that we are using the **default** notification sound which is user configurable under settings. If you could, try it in an emulator and if it works, check your phone settings. Also your phone must not be in silent mode, just in case.

Comment: works like charm thanks @sebasira